# Can't load txt file with numpy in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, visual-studio-code

```
import numpy as np
dat=np.loadtxt('sample.txt',skiprows=0,dtype=float)
print(dat.shape)
```

**I'm trying to load txt file with numpy in VScode, but it displays such error**

```
dat=np.loadtxt('sample.txt',skiprows=0,dtype=float)     
File "C:\Users\asadb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 961, in loadtxt
 fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
File "C:\Users\asadb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 195, in open
 return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
File "C:\Users\asadb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 535, in open
 raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: sample.txt not found.
```

Two files, .py file and .txt file, are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the directory to save .txt file then it moved!! Two files, .py that you want to move and .txt shouldn't be together in the same file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer you gave yourself is not the answer.
In VSCode you have multiple ways of opening a file. If you open a file directly. It does not always take the directory with it. If you were to load in a textfile. It would not search for it in your .py file directory (Whatever it may be). But it would search in your Python executable or VSCode directory. I recommend navigating to File --> Open Folder. In VSCode. And opening the folder where your .py file is located. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!! I did as you told me, and could run it!
I could run it whether txt file is in the same file with .py file or not. Solution was whether where you are. and where is a file. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Yeah, it has bamboozled me quite a lot too ;)